# Radio Station using Android is that possible?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I got a project where i need to use my Android phone as a **radio station**.It means,i need to  produce  sound  or song from my android phone and upload those to a server and from server; users can hear those sounds and songs live;almost,like an internet radio.

Is that possible in Android phones?If so how can i implement that?

Comment: you got the solution of this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) class to play radio station.  You need to pass radio station's url init.

for example This is one radio station's url http://shoutcast2.omroep.nl:8104/

So, Now initialise Media Player's object with it as follows,

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(“http://shoutcast2.omroep.nl:8104/”); 
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     player.start();
            } 

});
```

You can download example code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/downloads/detail?name=StreamingRadio.zip)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is download spreaker 
This a wonderful application that will help you develop a radio station on your android phone and it's free free free here the website spreaker.com write back it's working fine and you can also listen to my program (oxse) on spreaker

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit to general, but let's be tolerant and answer it.. 
With Android almost everything is possible :D

You need to define what you mean by "producing" of sound.. If it is some process of generating music on mobile device, it is possible! If you want to share music from your mobile SDcard, again you can do it..
2nd thing you need to decide is how you want to distribute music, as stream or as files (services like spotify, youtube or grooveshark). Then you need to start with simple things to gain knowledge of technologies you would need for this project which is not simple at all..

Anyway I hope, you got a clue about size.. Probably you didn't expect we to write your code so next steps are up to you.. Welcome to Android wonderland and good luck with projects..

Comment: for example i say some thing live through my phone on that time my sound should be hear to others who use my application

Comment: As I said everything is possible to make.Probably because of a lot of reasons there will be some delay between transmit and receive moment.But as I said u need to plan a lot of things and think how would u solve them, before u start with work.  

For example I doubt network coverage will give u really good signal to make this streaming work continuously and without interruptions. On the other side if u will use wireless why would you use phone and not PC?  so whole idea is a bit hmmm..maybe you should rethink about it and exclude use of phone in this case..Hope I made u think more about it..